# Ejecutar funciones dinámicamente

Tags: c#, string, reflection, compilacion

Necesito ejecutar dinámicamente una línea de código, más específicamente, ejecutar una función con parámetros en una sola cadena, como esta:

```
string code = "print(\"hello world\");"
compute(code);
```

De:

```
void print(string text)
{
   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

También en el caso de más de un parámetro:

```
string code = "sumAplusB(\"23\", \"4234\");"
compute(code);
```

De

```
string sumAplusB(string a, string b)
{
   return (a + b)
}
```

¿Es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Depende de qué tan elaborado quieres que sea, puedes necesitar crear o hacer uso de diferentes cosas. Por ejemplo, podrias hacer un pequeño código que solo detecte funciones. Encontrando cual es su nombre y los parámetros a enviar. Posteriormente podrías decidir que función llamar mediante condicionales o obtenerla mediante Reflection. Otra opción para nada fácil es crear un evaluador de expresiones.